# qTranslate inside PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, translation, qtranslate

There are a few things that won't translate on my website that are inside PHP.  Since it's inside PHP, the normal qTranslate quick tag won't work.  Is there a simple code that could help me translate these words?  Should it go on the same page where the translations are located?

This is the code for the what I need translated inside the PHP (Location:, Venue:, etc):

```
 <div class="event-text">
  <h2 class="event-title">' . get_the_title($post->ID) . '</h2>
    <ul class="event-meta">';
    if ($event_location != null) {
        echo '
      <li><span>Location:</span>' . $event_location . '</li>';
    }
    if ($club != null) {
        echo '
      <li><span>Venue:</span>' . $club . '</li>';
    }                   
    if ($event_allday == 'yes'){            
        echo '<li><span>Length:</span>All Day</li>';           
    } elseif ($tstart) {            
        echo '<li><span>Length:</span>' . $tstart . '';            
    } if ($tend) { 
        echo ' – ' . $tend . '</li>';
    }                
    echo '
      <li>';
    if (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'event_out', true) == 'yes') {
        echo '<div class="event-cancel-out"><p>Sold Out</p></div><!-- end .event-cancel-out -->';
    } elseif (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'event_cancel', true) == 'yes') {
        echo '<div class="event-cancel-out"><p>Canceled</p></div><!-- end .event-cancel-out -->';
    }elseif (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'event_free', true) == 'yes') { 
        echo '<div class="event-cancel-out"><p>Free Entry</p></div><!-- end #event-cancel-out -->';
    } else {
        echo '<div class="event-tickets"><a href="' . $event_ticket . '" >Buy Tickets</a></div><!-- end #event-tickets -->';
    }
    echo '</li>
    </ul><!-- end ul.event-meta -->';
    echo '
        ' . the_content() . '                                
</div><!-- end .event-text -->';
```

Comment: What do you mean by "inside PHP"? Is this a theme file?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a theme file for Wordpress.  I fixed these by changing to the following codes:

```
echo __("<li><span><!--:en-->Location: <!--:--><!--:ja-->場所:<!--:--></span>") . $event_location . '</li>';

echo '<div class="event-cancel-out"><p>' . __('<!--:en-->Sold Out<!--:--><!--:ja-->売り切れ<!--:-->') . '</p></div><!-- end .event-cancel-out -->';
```